# Ethernet network randomly disconnects

Tags: networking, ethernet, mate

I installed Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 on my Dell Dimension 4700 Desktop. The Ethernet network randomly disconnects after a few minutes of use and in order to get a connection I have to disconnect and reconnect the Ethernet cable to work again. The icon on the panel indicates is connected. It worked fine before installing Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 using other Ubuntu flavours. I have two (2) hard drives, one with Mate and the other with another that's not a Ubuntu Distro (would rather not say).  The disconnection happens on both Distros. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same. I suspect it may be something about power management for this device, but didn't find the solution yet. (In my case the applet shows 'disconnected')